# How to avoid creating of empty object?

Tags: c++, function, object, pointers, set

I am making my homework and I have 2 functions unionRect and intersectRect.I am creating a set of my first class Rectangle from a file. I have to return the union and intersect rectangle of that oColl.I am having a problem with returning the values because the object returns two 0 values.

I have tried to return different things but I couldn't do it.

This is from the first class Rectangle

```
Rectangle unionRect(const Rectangle& rec) const {
            int ux1, ux2, uy1, uy2;
            ux1 = min(ix1, rec.ix1);
            uy1 = min(iy1, rec.iy1);
            ux2 = max(ix2, rec.ix2);
            uy2 = max(iy2, rec.iy2);
            Rectangle a(ux1, ux2, uy1, uy2);
            return a;
    }
```

This is second class RectangleCollection function to read from file

```
RectangleCollection(const string& strFileName) {
        ifstream ifile(strFileName.data());
        copy(istream_iterator<Rectangle>(ifile), istream_iterator<Rectangle>(), inserter(oColl,oColl.begin()));
    };
```

this is my RectangleCollection class function for union Rect

```
Rectangle calcUnionColl() {
        set<Rectangle>::iterator it;
        Rectangle a;
        for (it = oColl.begin(); it != oColl.end(); ++it) {
         a = unionRect(*it);
        }
        return a;

    }
```

and the .txt file is

```
5 5 10 10
6 6 12 12
```

but when i call calcUnionColl it returns me

```
x1:0 x2:6 y1:0 y2:12
```

I expect the output to be x1:5 x2:6 y1:5 y2:12.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem could be with bits and pieces of code. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are not union'ing all of the `Rectangle`s together that are in the collection.  You are union'ing each individual `Rectangle` only with the one `Rectangle` that `calcUnionColl()` is called on, and then you return the result of just the last union that was performed.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Rectangle {
public:
    ...
    Rectangle unionRect(const Rectangle& rec) const;
    ...
}

Rectangle Rectangle::unionRect(const Rectangle& rec) const {
    int ux1, ux2, uy1, uy2;
    ux1 = std::min(ix1, rec.ix1);
    uy1 = std::min(iy1, rec.iy1);
    ux2 = std::max(ix2, rec.ix2);
    uy2 = std::max(iy2, rec.iy2);
    return Rectangle(ux1, ux2, uy1, uy2);
}

...

class RectangleCollection {
public:
    ...
    Rectangle calcUnionColl() const;
    ...
}

Rectangle RectangleCollection::calcUnionColl() const {
    Rectangle a;
    if (!oColl.empty()) {
        std::set<Rectangle>::iterator it = oColl.begin();
        a = *it++;
        while (it != oColl.end()) {
            a = a.unionRect(*it++);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me!Changed only calcUnionColl

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Remy Lebeau has a minor issue. If `oColl` is empty, `calcUnionColl` will return the the default-constructed value of `a`. So if the default-constructed value of `a` is `x1:0, x2:0, y1:0, y2:0` then if `calcUnionColl` returns that value, it is impossible to know if that is the actual union of the values in `oColl`, or if 
`oColl` was empty.

A common trick when finding the the maximum value of multiple `int`s is to initialize the running maximum with `INT_MIN`. And in the same way, when finding a minimum value, we initialize the the running minimum with `INT_MAX`.

Finding the union of rectagles is nothing more than finding the min/max value of the rectangles corner coordinates, so we can use the above trick.

For instance if `a = {x1:INT_MAX, x2:INT_MIN, y1:INT_MAX, y2:INT_MIN}`, then when calculating the union of `a` and any rectangle `b`, we will have:

```
b.x1 <= a.x1  // a.x1 == INT_MAX
b.y1 <= a.y1  // a.y1 == INT_MAX
b.x2 >= a.x1  // a.x1 == INT_MIN
b.y2 >= a.y2  // a.y2 == INT_MIN
```

So the union of `a` and `b` in this case will be `b`

Making use of this in `calcUnionColl()`:

```
// I assume the data-type for your rectangle coordinates is `int`.
// If you use another datatype, change this accoringly.

Rectangle RectangleCollection::calcUnionColl() const {
    int i_min = std::numeric_limit<int>::min(); // c++ way of getting INT_MIN
    int i_max = std::numeric_limit<int>::max(); // c++ way of getting INT_MAX

    set<Rectangle>::iterator it;
    Rectangle a(i_max, i_min, i_max, i_min);

    for (it = oColl.begin(); it != oColl.end(); ++it) {
        a = a.unionRect(*it);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now, if `oColl` is empty, `calcUnionColl()` will return `x1:INT_MAX, x2:INT_MIN, y1:INT_MAX, y2:INT_MIN`. This should be an invalid value for a rectangle since `x1>x2` and `y1>y2`, and should be easy to test for.

Sometimes you don't even have to test for it, since it often is an invalid value "that makes sense" for further calculations.